# Digits or Characters in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to take input and validate whether the input is a town or uk postcode. If it is a town (all letters) then pass through the if, if it is a postcode I need to strip the last tow characters off.

This worked for postcode:

```
if (preg_match('/[^0-9]+$/',$keyword)) {
    //SEE IF LAST 2 CHARS ARE LETTERS
    $last3chars = substr($keyword, -2);
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $last3chars)) {
        $keyword = substr($keyword,0,-2);
    }
}
```

And this works for town:

```
if(preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]+$/',$keyword)) {
    //SEE IF LAST 2 CHARS ARE LETTERS
    $last3chars = substr($keyword, -2);
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $last3chars)) {
        $keyword = substr($keyword,0,-2);
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to do it for both. any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `[^0-9A-Za-z]` part mean?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure how preg_match works, I got that from an answer to another question on here!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
is_int(substr($keyword, -2))
```

to check the postcode